# What is the correct way to link home and about page in django urls?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Right now what I am doing is this:

pages app > urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

project > urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This seems to work fine. I am able to go to the homepage and the about page fine, but I have seen other people do as in the following:

project > urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('about/', include('pages.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So basically, in the project urls file, the line

```
'path('about/', include('pages.urls')),'
```

is added as well as keeping the pages url the same as above.

So I was wondering what is the correct way of linking the about page in the project urls file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than a single view and a single url for it in your app and you want to put all of them after some url prefix you put that prefix in `urls.py` root.

So lets say you have `products` and `categories` views and you want them behind `api` prefix. That means `/api/products/` and `/api/categories/` then you would have in your "api" app:

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('products', views.products, name='products'),
    path('categories', views.categories, name='categories'),
]
```

In your root urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm, if I have a Pages app (to manage index and about pages), I do not need to have path('about/', include('pages.urls')) in my root urls.py file? I only need path('about', views.about, name='about') in my app urls.py file?

Comment: @pH4nT0M you only need `path('', include('pages.urls'))`

Answer (score 0):

in pages app you have to create urls.py file and link the url to the view

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),]
```

and in templates you can call the url with its name